# Laravel: Cannot migrate. General error: 1005

Tags: php, database, laravel

I am following Laracasts TDD and i ran into an error that i cannot resolve no matter what i do. When i try to migrate it shows me this error:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error:
>   1005 Can't create table `birdboard`.`#sql-14b8_86` (errno: 150
>   "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table
>   `projects` add constraint `projects_owner_id_foreign` foreign key
>   (`owner_id`) references `users` (`id`))

I know Laravel now uses unsignedBigInteger instead of unsignedInteger and bigIncrements instead of Increments. I've done all of that. 
Also into my AppServiceProvider.php i have added:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
    public function boot()
    {
        Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
    }
```

App Service Provider:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    public function register()
    {
        //
    }


    public function boot()
    {
        Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
    }
}
```

Create Projects table

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateProjectsTable extends Migration
{

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('projects', function (Blueprint $table) {

            Schema::dropIfExists('projects');
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('owner_id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->text('description');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('owner_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }


    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('projects');
    }
}
```

Can you please tell me whats wrong on my code and why do i get the error? 
https://prnt.sc/p5ku4x

Comment: Remove this line from create ```Schema::dropIfExists('projects');```. The issue seems to be with birdboard table and not with this one?

Comment: What version of Laravel?

Comment: Is `id` of `users` also `bigIncrement` ?

Comment: try to run `migrate:fresh`

Comment: @DinoNumić `birdboard` seems to be the name of the database, not a table name

Comment: Laravel 5.8 its the version.
If i delete Schema::dropIfExists('projects'); It runs this error: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (SQL: drop table if exists `users`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to edit the question and post your owner model too. there may be a difference in datatype.

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('owner_id');
```

verify if you are using the same data type in both tables for owern_id in foreign and id in the primary table

Comment: Yes this was the correct answer thankyou. Seemed like i was using Increments id on users table and unsignedBigInteger on projects table and that made the conflict.